# R gather similar files

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame of values sorted into similarly named groups: eg 001G, 002G, 003G, etc. There are other items in the table though with names that follow a similar convention but different letter. eg 001R, 002R, 003R. What I would like to do is select all of the files that end in R and all of the ones that end in G. I tried [["***G"]] and [["???G"]] to no avail. Any hints?

Comment: '...select all the files...' do you mean data frame rows (which may somehow refer to files)?  Can you edit your question and add the result of `str(data frame)`?

Comment: my mistake, yes I mean the items in the data set that are labeled with a variable identifier which ends in an R or a G.

Comment: Sounds like 2 of the 3 current answers will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some made up data that sounds like what you describe:

```
set.seed(1)
fn <- paste(1:10, sample(c("R", "G", "S"), 10, replace = TRUE), sep = "") 
df <- data.frame(file = fn, x = 1:10)
```

which gives:

```
   file  x
1    1R  1
2    2G  2
3    3G  3
4    4S  4
5    5R  5
6    6S  6
7    7S  7
8    8G  8
9    9G  9
10  10R 10
```

To select just the ones ending in R or G, do this:

```
keep <- grep("G|R", df$file)
df <- df[keep,]
```

See `?grep` for details of the selection process, which you can control to a high degree.  The result is:

```
   file  x
1    1R  1
2    2G  2
3    3G  3
5    5R  5
8    8G  8
9    9G  9
10  10R 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `file_names <- dir()[grep('R$', dir())]`

Change first argument in `grep()` into `'G$'` will grasp files have names end with 'G'

If they have suffixes, just try `'R[.]csv$'`

Answer (score 1):

I am using the grep function here -
Taking sample data -

```
> x<-c("001G", "002G", "003G","001R", "002R", "003R")
> a <- x[grep("G", x)]
> a
[1] "001G" "002G" "003G"
> b <- x[grep("R", x)]
> b
[1] "001R" "002R" "003R"
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. However, I believe it somehow serves the purpose.

Comment: thanks but it didn't quite work. each item like 001G, 002G is the identifier for a column it a data frame with the data about that item. when I used grep, it sorted the item id's but didn't take the data from the other columns along. From the original dataframe of 207 observations of 17 variables, I get back 207 observations of 0 variables when I do str(x)